# How to create an Document template and then Converting to PDF using C# WPF?

Tags: c#, pdf, converters

I would like to create a document template and then process, via WPF application, this template (adding specific information) to export the result via PDF.

Do you know the best way to handle pdf documents? I have syncfussion library.

Using C# language

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**PDF Forms templates**](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/acrobat/pdfs/adobe-acrobat-xi-create-form-or-template-tutorial_ue.pdf) and then populate them with iTextSharp dynamically.

Here is example: [Fill in PDF Form Fields using the Open Source iTextSharp Dynamic Link Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23112/Fill-in-PDF-Form-Fields-using-the-Open-Source-iTex)

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must have the acrobat reader for converting the simple document to the pdf format. When you type the information in the document then save it in the desired drive and then choose the option in the file type pdf format and select ok.